# Time Complexity of Dependent for loop

Tags: algorithm, loops, time-complexity, complexity-theory, probability

```
string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
{
    int val = str[i];
    while(val > 0)
    {
       sum = val % 62;
       val = val / 62;
    }
}
```

I know that parent loop executes n+1 time and the child loop executes (val)^(1/62) times. For parent loop time complexity will be O(n) but don't find a way to calculate for child loop. So, What will be the time complexity of the above program ?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the length of the string be written as n.

```
n = str.length();
```

Now, the outer for-loop iterates for the whole length of the String,i.e., ***n*** times. Hence,outer for-loop complexity is O(n).

Talking about child loop, the inner while loop executes (val)^(1/62) times. So, you can consider the inner while-loop complexity as ***O(log<sub>62</sub> val)***.

All other statements take constant time-complexity.

Therefore,net time complexity = **O(n * log<sub>62</sub> val)**.

Last step is because of :-

> **If f1(n) = O(g1(n)) and f2(n) = O(g2(n)),then  f1(n) * f2(n) = O(g1(n)
>   * g2(n))**

As mentioned by `Edward Doolittle` in the comment, you could reduce it to **O(n * log<sub>2</sub> val)** as log bases can be converted to base 2 only with a constant division(by *log<sub>2</sub>62*).

Comment: Usually simplified as `O(n log val)`, as `log`s to any base are equivalent up to a constant by the chain rule for logarithms. Also since `val` depends on `i` you should take an average of `val`.

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle-Well,something must be left for OP too. BTW,averaging would be too cumbersome to include in the answer. And,I am including your first point. THANKS for suggestion...